# Counting number of fields in table (or feature class) using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes

ArcPy contains a [ListFields](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v00000012000000) method, which:

> Lists the fields in a feature class, shapefile, or table in a
>   specified dataset.

The resulting object has a `count` method, but I can't see how to return the field count from this (shouldn't this return an integer?).

Aside from iterating through the fields and incrementing a counter, how can I return the field count?

```
import arcpy
fields = arcpy.ListFields(<table>)
count = fields.count

[Dbg]>>> count
<built-in method count of list object at 0x0EDEABE8>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To count the number of items in any list (including a list of fields) you can use the Python [`len`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712227/get-the-size-of-a-list-in-python) function.

For example:

```
print len(fields)
count = len(fields)
```

or

```
print len(arcpy.ListFields(<table>))
count = len(arcpy.ListFields(<table>))
```